# Memory Optimization in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I need to load huge data sets in memory. Presently using kryo as a serializer for storing the objects in IMap. What are the better ways for optimising memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

Kryo serialization is already a very good serialization and tactic to optimize memory usage. You could go a little deeper by using IdentifiedDataSerializable but that involves a bit more manual programming. On one hand you can add more nodes to the cluster and therefore spread the data out further, on the other hand you can use Hazelcast HDMS to store the data offheap and move them out of the garbage collected area.

Is there any specific problem you try to solve right now?

Comment: Trying to optimise memory and query time. Any suggestions for reducing query time over large data (Presently using paging predicate) ?

Comment: You'll need more nodes to spead data and therefore queries over more machines / cpus. Also faster deserialization is better. You also might want to look into Portable serialization which supports partial deserialization of elements.